# C# How to combine progress bar with audio playing?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to use a progress bar that could reflect the audio currently playing, i.e the duration of the audio.

Below is a snippet of my program, it's setup to play an audio file on button click.

[image]

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable.  Please post your code as text in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C# How to combine progress bar with audio playing?

You could use [SMTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) directly that contains progress.

```
<MediaPlayerElement
    x:Name="mediaPlayerElement"
    Margin="0,0,10,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
    />
```

For costuming progress, we need get the media file's duration and the current music position.

We could get the music duration with `MediaOpened` event.

```
private async void Player_MediaOpened(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        MusicTime = (int)sender.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.TotalSeconds();

    });
}
```

And then we need calculate the value of progress bar(the max value is 100) in media `PositionChanged` event.

```
private async void PlaybackSession_PositionChanged(MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        CurentPosition = (int)sender.Position.TotalSeconds;
        progressbar.Value = (CurentPosition / MusicTime) *100;

    });
}
```